# Pug template can't find CSS

Tags: node.js, pug

I looked and it seems like this problem is usually related to a typo, however, I've checked mine a bunch of times and don't see that. The location where the console says it's looking is exactly where it should be:

```
html(lang="en")
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    div#card
      h4 Your Moon Story!
      p#story #{moon_story}
```

in my index.js

```
// express set-up
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static('/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(expressValidator()); // Add this after the bodyParser middlewares!
```

`style.css` is the name of my file, and `/stylesheets` is where it's at. It's looking at `localhost:5000/stylesheets/style.css`, which is exactly where it should be. Why is my CSS file not being found?

edit : moved it into public folder, its saying its not there still, even though I updated the path

Comment: You will have to show us your server-side node.js routes that you think are serving the `/stylesheets/style.css` file before we can help identify what is missing or wrong.  Remember, node.js does not serve any files by default so only files which have a specific route for them or  are included in a directory that is being served by something like `express.static()` will be fetched by the server.

Comment: this should actually be the answer for me, I thought I was doing it but I'm not. I was too busy checking my spelling to check for that. Thank You! **edit: nvm i was doing it, i just didnt see it at first glance, ill edit my code with that info**

Comment: So, now it's a question of whether you're doing the `express.static()` correctly.  The way you have things configured, the file on your server should be located at `/public/stylesheets/styles.css`.  Is that where it is?  Note, this is from a top level directory `/public/stylesheets`.

Comment: It was not before, but I moved it into the public folder and it isn't working, but the error I get in response does tell me that its looking there.

Comment: Where exactly is your `style.css` file on your server?  Please give me the full file path to it's location.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the `style.css` file in the same folder of the .pug file, this should work:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title Example
    style
      // Custom styles for this template
      include ../css/style.css
```

You can navigate into other folders using `../`

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use indentation while using pug, i wasted 2 hours due to incorrect indentation.